# Copy file to photo library using C++ / NDK (Android Development)

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android app using a third party framework written in C++ (interfacing with NDK). So I don't have access to the native Java commands and am quite new to this process.  I want to be able to copy an image that is saved in the local app directory, e.g. cache, to the public photo library on the sd card.  Problem is I have no idea how in C++ to do this.

In native Java development there are commands such as getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() that can make this process easy. Is there some way to achieve similar functionality in C++ so that I can: a) Obtain the current app directory and file path to the item I wish to copy, b) obtain the public photos directory, c) copy the file from a to b.

Many thanks for any code snippets or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find examples of calling getCacheDir() from C++ [on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ZephyrSL/modern-tutorials/src/f159fa978ca3/android_wrapper/jni/main.cpp) and for getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() [on github](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/xbmc/android/activity/XBMCApp.cpp). Copying a file can be as simple as reading and writing in a loop, see [How can I copy a file on Unix using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180079/how-can-i-copy-a-file-on-unix-using-c#2180788).