# chmod can't give all permissions

Tags: c, embedded, chmod

I am trying to change file permissions using chmod function in C program

```
chmod("/tmp/toBoard", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

But after program run I check permissions and get only

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
```

I run this program on Linux embedded board. toBoard is a file [copied inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180079/how-can-i-copy-a-file-on-unix-using-c) from other file from /var directory, source file has all permissions(set manually from terminal). When I tried to copy it manually and set permissions it worked, but when I copy the file and try give it all permissions - it fails without errors

```
copy("/var/www/defaults.dat", "/tmp/toBoard");
int err;
if(err = chmod("/tmp/toBoard", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)){
    perror("chmod");
}
struct stat buffer;
int status = stat("/tmp/toBoard", &buffer);
```

How can I set all permissions to green light?

Comment: You have to run it as the owner, in this case root. But you shouldn't use root unless you really have to, and certainly not for experimenting like this.

Comment: this works as given for me.  Have to ``#include <fcntl.h>`` to get the S_IRWXU etc constants

Comment: Running as root. I need this to be able to rewrite this file from webpage, but it has no permissions. Vorsprung, <sys/stat.h> contains all constants needed, thoug I tried your advice and it didn't help either

Answer (score 8):

As it stands, your call is correct but it is probably failing, and you're not checking the returned code. You could try:

```
if (chmod("/tmp/toBoard", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)) {
    perror("chmod");
    /* more error handling. */
}
```

In this instance it is likely a case of "Permission denied".

Comment: @PaulPonomarev Is `/tmp/` mounted in some funny way ? What happens if you try a different file ?

Comment: I have edited the main question to answer your question. /tmp is a folder on the board, that is emptied after reboot

Comment: @PaulPonomarev So if you go to a terminal and use the straight `chmod 777 /tmp/toBoard`, then what happens ?

Comment: All permissions `-rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: @PaulPonomarev Okay, do you have `strace` ? If so do a `strace chmod ... ` and see how it calls the `chmod` syscall.

Comment: If I understood you right you were asking for this: `execve("/bin/chmod", ["chmod", "..."], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0`

Comment: @PaulPonomarev Great! Look further down, it needs to do `chmod` or `fchmod` at some point. That's the line we're looking for.

Comment: no chmod or fchmod functions found, only open, close, write, read access, mmap2, mprotect, munmap, stat64, fstat64 and set_tls

Comment: @PaulPonomarev That's very odd. What system is this ?

Comment: (Embedded) Linux version 3.2.0-PD13.1.0

Comment: Whatever your chmod utility is, it's source is probably available.