# How can I transfer files from one folder to another folder using (C) under UNIX?

Tags: c, file, directory

I have a text file with the names of about 800 files I want to transfer from one folder to another. Basically, the text file looks like this :

```
file1.aaa (End of line)
file2.aaa
..
etc
```

I made this code, using the function 'rename' as everyone suggests on the internet :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )
{
    FILE *file = fopen ( "C:\\Users\\blabla\\ListOfFiles.txt", "r" );
    char path1[100] = "C:\\blabla\\folder1\\";
    char path2[100] = "C:\\blabla\\folder2\\";
    char *s1;
    char *s2;

    char line [20]; /* the file names won't be any longer than that */
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line,file) != NULL)
    {
        char *filePath1 = (char *) malloc((strlen(path1) + strlen(line) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        char *filePath2 = (char *) malloc((strlen(path2) + strlen(line) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        filePath1 = strcpy(filePath1, path1);
        filePath2 = strcpy(filePath2, path2);
        strcat(filePath1,line);
        strcat(filePath2,line);


       if (rename(filePath1, filePath2) != 0)
       {
           perror("wrong renaming");
           getchar();
       }

       free(filePath1);
       free(filePath2);

    }

    fclose (file);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I print the filepaths I get the expected results, but the program stops running when it's supposed to run the 'rename' function, because of an invalid argument problem.
I looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/ and noticed that it says the arguments of rename() should be const char*, could this be where the problem come from ? But if so, I don't see how I could turn my arguments into 'const', since I need to update them as I read my initial text file.

Comment: Are you solving a general problem, or do you really just want to copy the set of files once? Your operating system will have *far superior* tools for that.

Comment: Do want to write C or C++ code?

Comment: Use your OS's shell. You will get this done in ten minutes. This should help: [Using the FOR command to copy files listed in a text file](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2004/03/30/using-the-for-command-to-copy-files-listed-in-a-text-file/)

Comment: The target folder exists? Is it empty? If not, can you overwrite?

Comment: What is exactly the error message you get?

Comment: 1)Yes this is part of a more general thing
    2 & 3) C, I changed that 
    4) Yes it does
    5) "wrong renaming" : Invalid Argument

Comment: `fgets() reains the '\n' in the read string; you'll have to strip that before using the "filename"

Comment: Other way to use system call and put standard cp or mv calls to move file from one directory to another.

Comment: I still don't know why my code doesn't work, but I've found a way thanks to Krumia's link to temporarily fix my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code that builds the file paths is horribly over-complicated but should work. To simplify it, remove the `malloc()` and just use two statically-sized arrays. Also, for the future, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

You're misunderstanding the `const` thing, it means that `rename()` won't change the characters pointed at by its two arguments. It's a way to say "these two pointers point at data which is input-only to this function, there will be no attempt to modify that data from inside the function". You should always `const` argument pointers when possible, it helps make the code *much* clearer.

If you're getting "invalid argument", that probably means the files aren't being found. Print out the filenames to help you verify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on how const things work.
The filepaths are correct as far as I can tell by printing them

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at:

[How can I copy a file on Unix using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180079/how-can-i-copy-a-file-on-unix-using-c)

And replace "/bin/cp" for "/bin/mv" in that code.

Hope it helps!