# C - copy a file

Tags: c, file-copying

I am learning C, and:

I see a way to delete a file

```
remove (f_name);
```

a way to rename a file:

```
rename(old_f_name, new_f_name);
```

but I cannot find a way to copy a file. Can this be true?

```
copy(old_f_name, new_f_name);  //gives an error.
```

Must I write a routine to open the file, read through it's contents, and write it?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Search this site for **[c] copy file**.

Comment: Also see [How can I copy a file on Unix using C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180079/how-can-i-copy-a-file-on-unix-using-c)

Comment: So, what I am seeing is, removing and renaming files is easy, copying is hard. Geez, that seems like such a basic, necessary function that someone would have defined a standard for it by now. I get it is OS dependent, but come-on.

Comment: I'm sure that when you implement your very own `copy_file()` and account for all the possible permutations and bits (how to show a progress, what to do with data streams, how to handle removable storages, offline storages, permissions, going from one type of filesystem to another, etc, etc, etc) you'll change your tone