# Unix: Copy file from current to another directory in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, directory, copy

I am trying to make a copy program that allows me to copy file from current directory to another directory. 
I am using open(), creat(), read(), write() so far.

For example: 
So far i can only copy the file to my current directory.

I have a folder name **A_folder** and a file name **file_1** and i want to copy **file_1** from my current directory to **A_folder**.

Can someone please help me?

Code and image are shown below

What I can do now:
./copy file1 copy_file

What I want is:
./copy file1 ./folder copy_file

Comment: Please how is `av` defined and initialised/set?

Comment: okay i've update the,

Comment: You want to put the call to `perror()` before the one to `fprintf()` to avoid misleading output form `perror()`. And please provide the errors you get and as well the input you used to provoke them.

Comment: i dont have any error, I just don't know how to copy the file into another directory

Comment: I've update it again

Comment: Your error check for the number of arguments is too late; you've already crashed if zero or one arguments were supplied.

Comment: Good point, I'll fix that shortly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I copy a file on Unix using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180079/how-can-i-copy-a-file-on-unix-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a helper function that constructs the path you need, `A_folder/file_1`, when given `A_folder` and `file_1`.

   A typical example of such a function is

   ```
   char *combine_path(const char *dir, const char *name)
   {
       /* Calculate the lengths of the path components.
          If the respective parameter is NULL, the length is zero .*/
       const size_t  dirlen = (dir) ? strlen(dir) : 0;
       const size_t  namelen = (name) ? strlen(name) : 0;

       char         *path, *p;

       /* We allocate <dir> + '/' + <name> + '\0'. */
       path = malloc(dirlen + namelen + 2);
       if (!path) {
           errno = ENOMEM;
           return NULL;
       }

       /* Let p point to the current position in the
          resulting path. */
       p = path;

       /* If there is a directory part,
          copy it, and append a '/' after it. */
       if (dirlen > 0) {
           memcpy(p, dir, dirlen);
           p += dirlen;
           *p = '/';
           p += 1;
       }

       /* If there is a name part, copy it. */
       if (namelen > 0) {
           memcpy(p, name, namelen);
           p += namelen;
       }

       /* Append a NUL char, '\0', to terminate the
          dynamically allocated buffer.
          This turns it into a C string. */
       *p = '\0';

       /* Return the pointer to the dynamically-allocated
          memory, containing the concatenated paths
          as a single string. */
       return path;
   }
   ```

   Note that the above function returns a dynamically allocated copy, so you should `free()` the result when you no longer need it.
2. I prefer much more explicit error checking. Consider:

   ```
   int copy_file(const char *frompath, const char *topath)
   {
       struct stat frominfo, toinfo;
       char        data[BUFFERSIZE];
       ssize_t     n;
       int         src, dst, cause;

       if (!frompath || !*frompath ||
           !*topath || !*topath) {
           fprintf(stderr, "copy_file(): NULL or empty file name!\n");
           return errno = EINVAL;
       }

       src = open(frompath, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
       if (src == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open file: %s.\n", frompath, strerror(cause));
           return errno = cause;
       }
       if (fstat(src, &frominfo) == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot get file statistics: %s.\n", frompath, strerror(cause));
           return errno = cause;
       }

       dst = open(topath, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, frominfo.st_mode & 0777);
       if (dst == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot create file: %s.\n", topath, strerror(saved_errno));
           errno = cause;
       }

       while (1) {
           char *p, *q;

           n = read(src, buffer, sizeof buffer);
           if (n == 0) {
               /* End of input. */
               cause = 0;
               break;
           } else
           if (n < 0) {
               /* Error (or interrupt, EINTR). */
               if (n == -1)
                   cause = errno;
               else
                   cause = EIO; /* n < -1 is a bug. */
               fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error: %s.\ņ", frompath, strerror(cause));
               break;
           }

           p = buffer;
           q = n;
           cause = 0;
           while (p < q) {
               n = write(dst, p, (size_t)(q - p));
               if (n > 0)
                   p += n;
               else
               if (n == -1) {
                   cause = errno;
                   break;
               else {
                   /* Bug; should never occur. */
                   cause = EIO;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (cause) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s: Write error: %s.\n", topath, strerror(cause));
               break;
           }
       }

       /* Failed? */
       if (cause) {
           unlink(topath);
           return errno = cause;
       }

       if (fstat(dst, &toinfo) == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot get file information: %s.\n", topath, strerror(cause));
           unlink(topath);
           return errno = cause;
       }

       /* from may be a device; if so, its size
          will be zero. */
       if (frominfo.st_size > 0 &&
           frominfo.st_size != toinfo.st_size) {
           cause = EIO;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: File size mismatch!\n", topath);
           unlink(topath);
           return errno = cause;
       }

       /* Careful closing. */
       if (close(src) == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing file: %s.\n", frompath, strerror(cause));
           unlink(topath);
           return errno = cause;
       }

       if (close(dst) == -1) {
           cause = errno;
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing file: %s.\n", topath, strerror(cause));
           unlink(topath);
           return errno = cause;
       }

       /* Success. */
       return errno = 0;
   }
   ```

   Note the pattern how I use `p` and `q` pointers to write the read buffer contents in possibly more than one part. This can occur, if the source file is local, and the target file is on some wonky filesystem. There is no *requirement* that `write()` should either write the entire buffer or return with an error code; short writes -- where only some of the initial data in the given buffer was written -- are perfectly okay, and do occur in some situations. The above is my preferred way to handle those.

   Many consider this level of error checking -- especially checking the result value of `close()`, since at this point in time many operating systems (including Linux) never return an error there -- foolish or at least paranoid.

   I personally consider this kind of error checking *"robust"*, because I want my code to tell me, as the user, if anything untoward happened; I definitely do not want it to just *assume* everything went fine, I want it to be paranoid about it. (I am not saying that OP's code does not check error codes; I'm only saying this version is more careful and vocal about it.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Would you mind explain solution 1 in more details? Some of the function are out of my understanding. X (

Comment: @mmm: I re-commented the `combine_path()` function. Can you understand it now? You can find the documentation for [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [`strlen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html), and [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) at the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html), i.e. running `man 3 malloc`, `man 3 strlen`, or `man 3 memcpy` at the command line.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last thing, any recommendation for Linux programming in C? I wish I can be the one solving question instead of asking it.

Comment: @mmm: Unfortunately, no -- but I love your attitude :). Most of the tutorials and guides on the web are quite poor. There are two things that you can look for in tutorials, though. When reading input line-by-line, a good tutorial should show how to do it using POSIX.1-2008 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). When dealing with network connections, the tutorial should use [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html). Any tutorial that deals with those topics but use something else are not worth reading.